# SQL Server bcp with xp_cmdshell Error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to export a table into a file using the `xp_cmdshell` procedure and the `bcp` utility.

```
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from Test.dbo.login"
                            queryout "test.txt" -S MyServer -T -c'
```

The error that I get is this one:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

I've found that this could be linked with permission with the SQL Server Agent service. What I've found, though, is that SQL Server Agent service is disabled with SQL Server 2008 Express.

So is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: `EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from Test.dbo.login"
queryout "C:\test.txt" -S MyServer -T -c'` or any other location you have permission, set direct path, don't rely on relative paths

Comment: SQL Server **Express** does *not have* SQL Server Agent. See [SQL Server Express Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and read the section "SQL Server Features Not Supported in SQL Server Express"

Comment: This should not have anything to do with SQL Agent.

Comment: Are you a SysAdmin on this SQL Server? And if so, how do you usually login to it to get your SysAdmin rights?

Comment: Now, im testing it on my local sql server, I'm SysAdmin and i login with Windows Integrated Secury.
If I try for exaple to run "dir C:\" with xp_cmdshell it works fine.
Another strange thing is that if I run the same command (bcp) on a cmd window it works fine, the only problem comes when I run the bcp command through Sql Server